# Sharepoint 2010: Creating Feature.xml and Elements.xml using notepad

Tags: feature

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am learning Sharepoint 2010 and trying to dive deep. What I am doing right now is to create a content type and fields using declarative programming in notepad and then deploying the feature.xml to sharepoint. I have all that part correct and the feature is deploying correctly. However, what I need to know is how to set the scope url?

For example, in my feature.xml I have the scope set to web. However, there is no element where i can define the scope url. Therefore, the feature is being deployed across the farm (which i dont want). I want it to be sandboxed to a particular site because the scope has been to web.

Please help me out from your massive experience.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you deploying the feature? You should have the option to deploy to a single site collection and only activate the feature on one web site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing a lot of different terms, let me try to clarify:

- There is no such thing like a scope url. Features are either Web, Farm, SiteCollection/Site or WebApp scoped.
- You can scope a feature for a web - then its available for all webs not just one. When you activate it, you activate it just for one web.

you can see all available features here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx

Allow me the comment that you make your life more complicated than it should be :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I apologize for the late reply from my end. What I had meant was when you setup a project in visual studio, the IDE prompts for the site and whether the solution is FARM or SANDBOXED. This setting is then used to deploy the solution. Once that is done, if you open the feature designer you can see that the scope is listed there, and the deployment URL is mentioned in project properties.

Now, let's say I don't want to use Visual studio but use notepad instead. How would i enter these 2 settings now?

Comment: With reference to life and making it complicated ....

Yeah, that's what everybody tells me but i have always wondered on it philosophically as well. Don't know how, but coming from a neutral observer such as yourself I think everybody is right :)

Comment: The deployment url is used when you deploy with Visual Studio. I assume it uses powershell to add/deploy the solution to the sitecollection - thats why they store it in the project and not in the feature.